# Lower bound on the smallest eigenvalue of a positive semidefinite matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, upper-lower-bounds, positive-semidefinite

Suppose $\bf W$ is a $n \times n$ matrix with every diagonal entry is $0$. Additionally, the row sum and column sum can be also uniformly bounded by a constant as $n\xrightarrow{} \infty$. Assume $|\rho|<1$ and $\bf I$ refers to the identity matrix. How can I lower-bound the smallest eigenvalue of the following positive semidefinite matrix?

$$({\bf I} -\rho {\bf W})^\top ({\bf I} -\rho {\bf W})$$

From my numerical experiments, I guess this result mainly depends on $\rho$ and is irrelevant to $n$. If $\rho$ is near $1$, the lower bound will be near $0$. While $\rho$ is near $0$, the lower bound would be much larger.

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gershgorin_circle_theorem

Comment: @YaroslavBulatov I have tried this theorem before, but it seems to be too loose to be greater than 0 uniformly.

Comment: Interesting question. My first through was to look at diagonally dominant theorems, but your conditions are not strong enough to ensure DD

Comment: Have you tried using the Sylvester criterion on the following? $$({\bf I} -\rho {\bf W})^\top ({\bf I} -\rho {\bf W}) - t {\bf I}_n \succeq 0$$

Comment: @YaroslavBulatov I suppose that using the Sylvester criterion needs to calculate a series of determinants, which is unknown for our $\bf W$. However, what I have tried is to find a upper bound of the maximum eigenvalue of $$A = ({\bf I}- \rho {\bf W})^{-1}({\bf I}- \rho {\bf W}^\top)^{-1} = ({\bf I} - \rho {\bf W} - \rho {\bf W}^\top +\rho^2 {\bf W^\top W})^{-1} = {\bf I} + \sum\limits_{k\geq 1} \rho^k ({\bf W} + {\bf W}^\top - \rho {\bf W^\top W})^k,$$ where $|\rho|<1$ might be useful.